# How can I use apt-cache to only search on descriptions of packages?

Tags: apt-get

I am wanting to search for every package that has a description of PDF. How do I do that with `apt-cache` or is there a different command I can use?

Comment: Do you _really_ want to search _just_ the description as you say, or do you also want to search the package names? You write "only descriptions", but is it a dealbreaker? 'apt-cache search pdf | grep -i pdf' only gives 9 more hits than limiting the search to _only_ the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
apt-cache search 'PDF' | grep ' - .*PDF'
```

This will give you only entries that have 'PDF' in their description.

Comment: Thanks. What does the hyphen do i.e. `- .`?

Comment: You see the output from `apt-cache search`? `grep` will print only the lines that matches the (in this case simplified) [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) '` - .*PDF`', which means that it only prints lines containing the pattern "[space][hyphen][space][any character]{the preceding match 0 or more times}PDF". ' - ' is what separates the package name from its description, so this will first print all packages that have "PDF" in its name OR its description, and then pick out only the latter.

Comment: There are, however, multiple (16 on my system) packages whose description contain "pdf" with small letters. The above command should be changed to "... | grep -i ' - .*pdf' to make the search case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

To use `apt-cache` you need to massage the output by yourself. Using `aptitude`, you can do

```
aptitude search '?description(pdf~))'
```

which does exactly what you want. See the aptitude reference manual (install `aptitude-doc-en` and look in `/use/share/doc/aptitude/` or use a [web interface directly](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/)) for more info regarding its [search syntax](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03.html).